# Knockout.js foreach not giving errors and not showing results

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following JS code:

```
that.ctrls.parcels = ko.observableArray([]);
r.data.forEach(function (d) {
    var pMapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(d);
    debugger;
    that.ctrls.parcels.push(pMapped);
});
ko.applyBindings(that.ctrls, document.getElementsByClassName('assist-entry')[0]);
```

My pertinent HTML code is this:

```
<div class="wrap assist-entry assist-entry--protest-affidavit">
...
 <div class="box box--milder assist__parcel-list" style="margin-top: 50px">
  <header class="box__header box--milder__header">
    <h4 class="box__title box--milder__title">
      Parcels: <span data-bind="text: parcels().length"></span>
    </h4>
  </header>
  <div class="box__body">
    <div class="wrap" data-bind="foreach: parcels">
      <div class="parcel">
        <header>
          <h5 class="parcel-id">
             <span class="lab">Parcel:</span>
             <span data-bind="text: Id"></span>
          </h5>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

When I get to the point where the `Parcels` collection is being built, I can step through the process and see that two parcels are being added to the collection.  When the UI finishes the process "2" properly appears in the list header for total number of parcels.  However, no parcel data shows up in the div containing the `foreach; parcels`.  Also, the Chrome debugger isn't reporting any errors or warnings so the binding seems to be executing properly.  What could the problem be?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the parts you've included. Are you sure r.data is a valid javascript object? What does r.data look like?

Comment: could you show us the contents of parcel() after it has data?

Comment: You apply bindings over a `div` with style `assist-entry`.  Is there the `<div>` you show in  this question a child of a `div` with this style `assist-entry`?

Comment: @JoseLuis Sorry for the late response-- I am in the South-East US, so we've been dealing with a Tropical Storm. Anyway, `assist-entry` is a style on a single div, that is a container of my collection. Is that what you're asking about? Also, `assist-entry` is applied only once, and isn't nested, nor does it appear as a sibling anywhere else in the document.

Comment: @RLH Still looking for a sample of r.data. I'm thinking maybe you should be using ko.mapping.fromJSON instead of ko.mapping.fromJS?